# [Azure]ScaleSet Ubuntu 22.04 Server with GUI - Gen2 ERROR purchased

Tags: azure, unix, azure-vm-scale-set

I'm trying to create a scale set with Ubuntu 22.04 Server with GUI - Gen2 but I have this error:

```
ffer with PublisherId: 'yaseensmarket1645449809728', OfferId: 'ubuntu-22-gui' cannot be purchased due to validation errors. For more information see details. Correlation Id: '6925d160-XXXX-46b1-87c4-XXXXXXX' The 'unknown' payment instrument(s) is not supported for offer with OfferId: 'ubuntu-22-gui', PlanId '2204'. Correlation Id '6925d160-XXXXX-46b1-87c4-XXXXXXX'.[{"The 'unknown' payment instrument(s) is not supported for offer with OfferId: 'ubuntu-22-gui', PlanId '2204'. Correlation Id '6925d160-XXXXX-46b1-87c4-XXXXXXXXX'.":"StoreApi"}] (Codice: BadRequest)
```

I think it's due to a compatibility error with my subscription (Visual Studio €50 per month).
Is there a version of Unix GUI (any) or similar (non-windows) compatible to create a scale set? Or do I necessarily have to change the type of subscription?

Br's
Fred

Create a scale set with Ubuntu 22.04 Server with GUI - Gen2

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to create virtual machine scale set got the same error like below:

```
message": "Offer with PublisherId: 'yaseensmarket16454498XXXX', OfferId: 'ubuntu-22-gui' cannot be purchased due to validation errors. For more information see details. Correlation Id: '92369e5d-37ce-4817-8281-XXXX' The 'unknown' payment instrument(s) is not supported for offer with OfferId: 'ubuntu-22-gui', PlanId '2204'. Correlation Id '92369e5d-37ce--8281-XXXX'.[{\"The 'unknown' payment instrument(s) is not supported for offer with OfferId: 'ubuntu-22-gui', PlanId '2204'. Correlation Id 'XXXXX-37ce-4817-8281-XXXX'.\":\"StoreApi\"}]"
```

[image]

According to [**MsDoc**](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/pricing/offers/ms-azr-0029p/) Visual Studio Enterprise subscribers with monthly Azure credit have the flexibility to use it for a wide range of Azure services and resources like virtual Machines, Web Apps, Cloud Services, Mobile Services, Storage, SQL Databases, etc...

> ***Note*** that there are ***some exceptions to what you can purchase with your monthly Azure credit*** Support plans, Application Insights, Visual Studio subscriptions, Azure DevOps, third-party branded products, products sold through Marketplace, and products otherwise sold separately from Azure Microsoft Azure Active Directory Premium are ***not covered by your monthly Azure credit***. ***You will be billed for any of these services used.***

***Reference***:

[Purchasing software and solutions from Azure Marketplace - Microsoft marketplace | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/marketplace/azure-purchasing-invoicing#purchase-validation-checks)